# How to round up a timestamp to nearest 5 minute value

Tags: perl, date, timestamp

I have this format for a timestamp:

2019-01-24T00:00:05.011719

How do I round this up to the nearest 5 minute value? in perl

Edit: Okay the question is pretty vague and lazy. But the question stays, just want to add information to my problem.

1. I don't know what kind of format that is, so if I know i can google, what function or method converts those kind of date formats.
2. 20190124000000 isn't this the correct 5 min value? I wanted it to be like that format by the way. But its too easy to be the correct approach, it makes me suspicious like answering math questions back in college. Anyway, I can just use regex for that.

Comment: What have you tried? I'm sure you know that on this forum, you require code, and a specific question regarding that code to get help.

Comment: do you know the timezone?  e.g. 2019-03-10T01:56:00.000000 in America/Los_Angeles rounds up to 2019-03-10T03:00:00.000000

Answer (score 3):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%FT%T.%6N',
    time_zone => 'UTC',       # Or 'local' or 'America/Toronto' or '-0500'
    on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('2019-01-24T00:00:05.011719');
$dt->set_formatter($format);  # Set default stringification format.

$dt->truncate( to => 'second' )->add( seconds => 1 ) if $dt->nanosecond;
$dt->truncate( to => 'minute' )->add( minutes => 1 ) if $dt->second;
$dt->add( minutes => 5 - ( $dt->minute % 5 ) ) if $dt->minute % 5;

say $dt;  # 2019-01-24T00:05:00.000000
```

Note that the format used by `2019-01-24T00:00:05.011719` is ambiguous if the associated time zone observes DST (because of the repeated hour in the fall).

Aside from that, the above code correctly handles discontinuities in the passing of time such as the ones that occur at DST changes, as long as the discontinuity starts and ends at a rounding point.

Comment: Question, why you add 1 after truncate? also what happens when its not divisible by 5? and why 5 minus dt%5?

Comment: Ohh okay, modulo, will return 0 if already 5, so meaning its already a 5 minute value right?

Comment: Re "*why you add 1 after truncate?*", Because you asked to round up

Comment: Re "*what happens when its not divisible by 5?*", It adds a sufficient number of minutes to make it divisible by 5.

Comment: okay so if its not 5 minute value, why we add 5 minus the remainder of the not 5 minute value? why not subtract instead?

Comment: Re "*why 5 minus dt%5?*", That's the number of minutes needed to be added to make the minute divisible by 5.

Comment: round up yaaahhhh sorry

Comment: Re "*why not subtract instead?*", We could subtract a negative number, but that would be weirder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be broken down to:

- pick a time period `N` time units
- pick a starting point (epoch) where the first (0th) time period starts
- parse the timestamp and convert it into "`X` time units since epoch"

  - integer division of `X` by `N` gives you the # of the period the timestamp lies in
  - the remainder of the division of `X` by `N` gives you the offset inside that period
  - if the remainder is exactly `0` (zero) then the timestamp is at the start of that period

Your requirements are

- `N` is 5 minutes, or 300 seconds
- let's use the standard [UNIX Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_Epoch), i.e. `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`
- you want to round up to the next period, unless the timestamp is exactly the start of a period.
- as you have not given a time zone, I assume [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for simplicity.

Just using core Perl, i.e. [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece), a solution would be:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use constant PERIOD => 5 * 60; # 5 minutes

use Time::Piece;

# timezone for Time::Piece->new()
$ENV{TZ} = "UTC";

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my($iso8601, $fractional) = split(/\./);

    # NOTE: time is interpreted as UTC
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($iso8601, '%FT%T');

    # calculate multiple of PERIOD and offset in that period
    my $index  = int($t->epoch / PERIOD);
    my $offset = $t->epoch % PERIOD + "0.${fractional}";

    # round up to next PERIOD unless time is exactly multiple of PERIOD
    $index++ if $offset > 0;

    # convert index back to epoch and generate new Time::Piece object
    # NOTE: timezone offset is set to $ENV{TZ} timezone
    my $t2 = Time::Piece->new($index * PERIOD, 0);

    print "$_ -> ", $t2->strftime('%FT%T'), "\n";
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
2019-01-24T00:00:00.000000
2019-01-24T00:00:05.011719
2019-01-24T00:04:59.999999
2019-01-24T00:05:00.000000
2019-07-24T00:00:00.000000
2019-07-24T00:00:05.011719
2019-07-24T00:04:59.999999
2019-07-24T00:05:00.000000
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
2019-01-24T00:00:00.000000 -> 2019-01-24T00:00:00
2019-01-24T00:00:05.011719 -> 2019-01-24T00:05:00
2019-01-24T00:04:59.999999 -> 2019-01-24T00:05:00
2019-01-24T00:05:00.000000 -> 2019-01-24T00:05:00
2019-07-24T00:00:00.000000 -> 2019-07-24T00:00:00
2019-07-24T00:00:05.011719 -> 2019-07-24T00:05:00
2019-07-24T00:04:59.999999 -> 2019-07-24T00:05:00
2019-07-24T00:05:00.000000 -> 2019-07-24T00:05:00
```

Comment: Re "*The problem can be broken down to:*", This approach assumes that *all* discontinuities in the passing of time in the user's time zone (such as the ones that occur at DST changes) both *start* and *end* on a multiple of `PERIOD`. This assumption is valid for the combination of the time zone you assumed is the user's time zone (UTC) and for the value of `PERIOD` in question, but it's not valid in general.

Comment: As long as the timestamp of a leapsecond (e.g. `2016-12-31T23:59:60`) isn't provided, your program handles leap seconds fine. It's because epoch time simply pretends they don't exists. Epoch time is the number of non-leap seconds since 1970 UTC. As far as Epoch time is concerned, `1483228800` is merely a very long second.

Comment: I suppose for `PERIOD = 10`, your program would round `2016-12-31T23:59:58` to `2017-01-01T00:00:00` when `2016-12-31T23:59:60` is technically closer. But I'm not convinced that's a problem. Most people pretend leap seconds don't exist.